# Sending unique value for each request in java

Tags: java, servlets

I have a requirement where i have to send unique value for each request and i have to validate that in my class for security purpose. any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Sorry but there is nowhere near enough information here to be able to answer the question.  Where does the unique value come from, what is its purpose, what have you done so far to attempt to solve this issue?

Comment: Define unique value ? Also state your problem clearly . we are not here to provide solutions for your requirements . so post us what have you tried?

Comment: More details please. Do you want to send a unique value from the servlet to a jsp and validate it?

Comment: send an UUID. Than there is no validation necessary...

Comment: I have a JSP Page and for security reasons i have to send a unique number for each request that i send from the JSP and i have to validate the unique number at the java side.

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of solutions to this problem as it depends on how unique it need to be.

You can use a `UUID.randomUUID()` to create an id which is highly like to be unique across multiple machines.

You can do

```
String str = uuid.toString();
```

and reverse this with

```
UUID uuid2 = str.fromString(str);
assert uuid.equals(uuid2); // true
```

---

You can use a counter like AtomicLong.  If you encode it in base 36, you get much shorter ids, but this is not unique between restarts or between processes.

A modification of this is you can use an AtomicLong which starts with `System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000` so you ids should be unique across restarts.

You can also use a JDBC database for unique values.  The downside is this is fairly complex and slow.

Comment: Thanks peter for the reply.  i want to  go with UUID and i am thinking of putting a hidden variable in JSP and it's value will be genrated by UUID, but how can i validate this number in the my action class ?. is there a method like UUID.getUUID and will this number be same as the one generated in JSP

Comment: @user2727493 I have added examples of translating to/from a String.

Comment: Thanks for the reply peter. how can i validate it in java side ?. i think i can put a hidden variable in JSP with UUID as a value but how can i validate it in java once i get control to controller.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add 1 to the value you last sent. That moves your problem to "*how long will it take to exhaust an n-bit counter*" and that's just a simple maths problem once you estimate how often you make a request.

Validation is easy - just keep enough history. A database would do that most simply for you.